# Building AOSP for Nexus 5, clang error

Tags: android, android-source, nexus-5

I'm attempting to build aosp, but make keeps failing with the following error. I have not been able to determine the cause/solution.

```
out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/arch/x86_64/quick_entrypoints_x86_64.o:function art_quick_instrumentation_exit: error: unsupported reloc 42
out/host/linux-x86/obj/SHARED_LIBRARIES/libart_intermediates/arch/x86_64/quick_entrypoints_x86_64.o:function art_quick_deoptimize: error: unsupported reloc 42
clang: error: linker command failed with exit code 1 (use -v to see invocation)
build/core/host_shared_library_internal.mk:51: recipe for target 'out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so' failed
make: *** [out/host/linux-x86/obj/lib/libart.so] Error 1
```

Setup:

```
PLATFORM_VERSION_CODENAME=REL
PLATFORM_VERSION=6.0.1
TARGET_PRODUCT=aosp_hammerhead
TARGET_BUILD_VARIANT=userdebug
TARGET_BUILD_TYPE=release
TARGET_BUILD_APPS=
TARGET_ARCH=arm
TARGET_ARCH_VARIANT=armv7-a-neon
TARGET_CPU_VARIANT=krait
TARGET_2ND_ARCH=
TARGET_2ND_ARCH_VARIANT=
TARGET_2ND_CPU_VARIANT=
HOST_ARCH=x86_64
HOST_OS=linux
HOST_OS_EXTRA=Linux-4.4.0-62-generic-x86_64-with-Ubuntu-16.04-xenial
HOST_BUILD_TYPE=release
BUILD_ID=M4B30Z
OUT_DIR=out
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

In build/Android.common_build.mk, the line

```
ART_HOST_CLANG := true
```

turns on clang build support by default.

Turn it off by simply commenting out the line. Or, if you want, make the condition `ifneq ($(WITHOUT_HOST_CLANG),true)` return false to skip the clause.